# PyQt6.QWidgets has no attribute qApp

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I am migrating (someone else his) code from pyqt5 to pyqt6 and the following code is giving me an error:

```
def quitApp(self):
        """ Exit application callback """
        QtWidgets.qApp.quit
```

It seems that this no longer works in pyqt6 (I get the error in the title). I tried to find how I am supposed to do this in pyqt6 but I could not find it, unfortunately.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QtWidgets.qApp` is appication instance, to obtain application instance in `pyqt6` you can call `QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()` method, but it's not necessary since all instance methods exposed in `QtWidgets.QApplication` as static methods (`QtWidgets.QApplication` implements singleton pattern), so to quit you can call `QtWidgets.QApplication.quit()` which does the same as `QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().quit()` does.

This works in `pyqt6` and in `pyqt5`.